# How to create a points layer without XY cordinates in my attribute table

Tags: point, table, xy

I have tried a few methods. I loaded a table and tried to join it with "add join" using the object ID as the the common attribute, but it did not join the table the way I planned. I ultimately created a new feature layer and manually creating the points which is more work than actually needs to be done besides the fact that the info I want it to link with the table was removed. Does anyone have any recommendations on creating points in a feature layer without (X,Y) coordinates?

[image]

Comment: What software? Please include sample datasets, in text.

Comment: Geocoding https://www.google.com/search?q=geocoding if you have something that looks like an address. ObjectIDs aren't good for joining tables as it would be extremely difficult to get them to match up, they are controlled by the database so you can't change them, try searching for a field that does match because there's a lot less work in an attribute join than in geocoding.

Comment: Welcome Ramon. It would be best in the future if you could mention the software you use, I guess it is ArcGIS but I may be wrong. As I know the Object ID may be created by the software you use, what would be the chances to have the external table would have the same ObjectID field or the same field with a difference name.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works